# How do I add a swap (Not a swap file) after installation of Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux, swap, dualboot

I am a dual user running Kali Linux and Windows 8.1 . A few days before, I had removed the swap partition that I had installed for Kali Linux during the installation, since my windows was running out of space. Now, I do not know how to make Kali Linux recognize the swap partition for it. The consequence I have to face is that it takes 2 full minutes to boot into Kali Linux. I am posting the system specs below:

> Manufacturer and Model: Dell Latitude E5440

> Version: Kali Linux Rolling 2020.3

I guess this is unimportant, but just posting it.

Thanks!

Another thing, I want Kali Linux to realize that I have given it a partition not during the installation procedure, but when it runs on the OS environment. GParted is not helping at all, although I try to provide it a Swap partition. It remains enabled, but during the next boot, Kali does not use it and it stays useless.

Comment: Nope, it does not.

Comment: **You literally said it did though in your answer.** You also said the accepted answer didn’t actually answer your question (or specifically you didn’t even use that solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to add a Swap File:  (I am working and posting in Kali Linux here)

You may need to add a file if you cannot add a partition without reinstalling Kali.

https://miloserdov.org/?p=2667

> If you do not have enough RAM, you can add a Swap file. If you do not
> have enough RAM with the existing swap partition, you can
>
> ```
> create a larger swap file and use only it
> create an additional swap file and use it together with the existing swap partition
> ```
>
> The advantage of swap file compared to swap partition is that you
> don’t need to partition your disks, and to enable/disable the swap
> partition you don’t even need to reboot the system.
>
> Let's start by checking what the size of the swap partition is for the
> system at the moment:      swapon --show
>
> So, there is a swap partition /dev/sda5 with a size of 4.9G.
>
> Suppose this is not enough for me and I want a swap file to be 10 GB
> in size. This file will be located in the root of the file system -
> that is, there should be enough space to accommodate this file.
>
> I create the file itself that will be used as a swap file:     sudo
> fallocate -l 10G /swapfile
>
> Set the correct permitions:    sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
>
> Format this file in swap:      sudo mkswap /swapfile
>
> And we enable the new swap file:   sudo swapon /swapfile
>
> Check again:   swapon --show
>
> We still have the swap partition /dev/sda5, and the swap file
> /swapfile 10G in size appeared.

When done, if boot time does not speed up, you will need to back up your documents and reinstall Kali.

Answer (score 0):

I really wanted a swap partition to be made, but the answer I got suggested that I create a swap file. That did not work, coz I got stuck at the last step -

> sudo swapon / swapfile

So now, I found an answer on this same web -
[How to enable linux swap partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/862994/how-to-enable-linux-swap-partition/862997)
This actually solved my booting problems and also, I am now able to hibernate since the swap partition is bigger than the RAM. But, good efforts from John, which I appreciate. People who want to make a swap file, can go with his answer, but people who want to stick around with swap partitions, can look at this answer.